# Shaft angular skew in hole

Tags: trigonometry

There is a shaft in a hole. One end of the shaft is at the end of the hole.
I know the diameter of the shaft (D.shaft) and the diameter of the hole (D.hole) and the depth of the hole (H).

D.shaft< D.hole.

How can I calculate the "A" (max skew) angle of the shaft?

I have basic trigonometric knowledge, and it seems not enough to solve it.

[image: SKETCH]

Thank you, Norbert

Comment: Hint: think about triangle similarity… in the 2 right angled triangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
$$ y+x= D_{shaft} \cos \alpha  + H \tan \alpha = D_{hole} \tag 1 $$

$$ D_{shaft} \cos \alpha  + H \tan \alpha = D_{hole}   $$
If $t= \tan \alpha, $

$$ D_{shaft} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}  + H t = D_{hole}  \tag 2 $$

Can you set up a polynomial in $~t?$

Comment: wow.. great.. I made this from your equation..
$Ds/sqrt(1+t^2)=Dh-H*t$

$Ds=sqrt(1+t^2)*(Dh-H*t)$

$Ds^2=(1+t^2)*(Dh-H*t)^2$

$Ds^2=(1+t^2)*(Dh^2-2H*t+H^2*t^2)$

$Ds^2=Dh^2-2H*t+H^2*t^2 + t^2*Dh^2-2H*t^3+H^2*t^4$

$Ds^2=H^2*t^4 -2H*t^3+ t^2*(H^2 + Dh^2) - 2H*t + Dh^2$


But that's all, quadratic equation is also too much, but I will try to check it on google :D
I thought it was easier question :)
Thank you